# How to multiply two input of different dimensions (keras_tensor element) in CNN keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Suppose that after giving input to a 2d-CNN, as the output of ith layer I have an `Output Shape: (None, 1, 3, 1)`. I also have another input with shape `(None, 50, 27, 1)` and what I want to multiply each element of columns 1-9 with the first element of (None, 1, 3, 1), each element of columns 10-18 with the second element of (None, 1, 3, 1) and each element of columns 19-27 with the third element of (None, 1, 3, 1). To summarize, what I want to do is as follows:

[image]

Doing this using lists is not difficult however, I want to do this in my keras model. Therefore, the type of my inputs are 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'. Do you have an idea about how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your inputs are `a` and `b`,

```
c = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(
    lambda x: tf.concat(
        [a*b for a, b in zip(
            tf.split(x[1], 3, axis=-2), 
            tf.split(x[0], 3, axis=-2)
            )
        ], axis=-2
        )
    )([a,b])
```

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to do that in Sequential API instead of Functional API. I think it is not possible to make using model.add(Lambda ...).

Comment: No it won't be. You have 2 inputs which by definition makes it not possible to use the Sequential api. You'll have to use the Functional api.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which is similar to [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73386383/5154274) but with [`tf.repeat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/repeat):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random.normal((2, 50, 27, 1))
y = tf.random.normal((2, 1, 3, 1))

repeated = tf.concat([tf.repeat(y[:, :, i:i+1, :], 9, axis=2) for i in range(3)], axis=2) # shape = [2, 1, 27, 1]
res = x * repeated # shape = [2, 50, 27, 1]
```

And using Keras model:

```py
x = tf.keras.layers.Input((50, 27, 1))
y = tf.keras.layers.Input((1, 3, 1))

res = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(
    lambda x: x[0] * tf.concat([tf.repeat(x[1][:, :, i:i+1, :], 9, axis=2) for i in range(3)], axis=2) 
)([x, y])

model = tf.keras.models.Model([x, y], res)
```